# Show class names and confidence values in Tensorflow multi-class classification

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, tensorflow.js, image-classification

I've trained my model in python and then converted the model so I could use it on my JS website. I have a brain tumor dataset, it has 4 classes:

1. Glioma
2. Menengioma
3. No tumor
4. Pituitary

So far I've done this:

```
<script>
    async function LoadModels(){  
               model = undefined;
               model = await tf.loadLayersModel("http://127.0.0.1:5500/modelsBrain/modelBrain.json");
               const pr = document.getElementById('photo');
               const image = tf.browser.fromPixels(pr);
               const image2 = tf.reshape(image, [1,200,200,3]);
               const prediction = model.predict(image2);
               alert(prediction.dataSync());
           }
           LoadModels();
</script>

// just predicting one photo
```

Which gives me an alert like [x, y, z, k]. And also I've created a .js file with classes target:

```
TARGET_CLASSES_BRAIN = {
    0: "Glioma",
    1: "Menengioma",
    2: "No Tumor",
    3: "Pituitary"
}
```

So, the thing I want to do is to have an output like:

**Glioma**: 0.001

**Menengioma**: 0.0004

**No tumor**: 0.99

**Pituitary**: 0.0086

I want to include both class names and confidence values. I'm new to the TensorflowJS, could you please direct me? Thank you so much in advance.

**UPDATE**: I also used a `softmax` function:

```
Dense(4, activation='softmax')
```

Comment: Could you please paste what is the output of `prediction.dataSync()` ?

Answer (score 0):

Here is a snippet that can help to get the label of a prediction

```
  const label = ['Glioma', 'Menengioma', 'No Tumor', 'Pituitary',]  
  // the code for prediction
  const prediction = model.predict(image2);
  const listIndexes = prediction.argMax(1).dataSync(); // get the class of highest probability
  labelsPred = Array.from(listIndexes ).map(index => label[index])
  console.log(labelsPred)
```